# Unable to load video thumbnail from Uri in android Q

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-10.0

i have tried this code. but not able to get thumbnail any more.
Also tried different approaches to get thubmnails. 
what should i change for android Q?

```
  private void getVideoList(){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                String[] projection = new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID,
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION,
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.SIZE,enter code here
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA,`enter code here`
                };
                String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION + " <= ?";
                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                };

                String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC";

                try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        sortOrder
                )) {





                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: try adding  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest application tag

Comment: not working @ManoharReddy

Comment: Where is your thumbnail code?

Comment: i am using                        Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);

        Bitmap thumb=null ;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            try {
                thumb=  ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(contentUri)));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        holder.thumb_image.setImageBitmap(thumb); @KasımÖzdemir

Comment: Maybe you can get an exist image this way but not get video thumb.

Comment: did you find a working solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method to get video thumb:

```
public static Bitmap getThumbVideo(Context context, Uri videoUri){
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context, videoUri);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

It works on all current versions of Android.

Comment: There is another problem  when i am performing some on that uri  it show an exception that is file not found what should i do for this

Comment: If you get this error, uri is invalid. So a file with the specified pathname does not exist as you think.

Comment: my video url still not loading